# multiple uploaded file's title

Tags: php, html, file, file-rename

i m trying to transfer multiple files from my computer to a folder in my project by $_FILES using one input ,the files are moved successfully but the titles are duplicated each time related with last file's title[image: like this],any solution ??? maybe i should use foreach in place of for loop ???

My code :

```
<body>
    <!--images adding-->
    <form action=" " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:100px">
        <div class="display-4">Ajouter images</div>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file[]" size="50" class="btn" style='background-color:#374180;color:yellow;' multiple>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="btn cursor" type="submit" value="Upload" name='but' style='background-color:#314796;color:yellow;' />
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['but'])) {
        $chemin = 'uploads/';
        $fileCount = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
        echo $fileCount;

        for($i=1;$i<=$fileCount;$i++) {
            $chemin = $chemin.basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$chemin)) {
                var_dump($_FILES);
            } else {
                echo 'Error uploading ';
            }
        }
    }
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time through the loop you're appending another name to `$chemin`, making the name longer and longer. Use a different variable for the directory than the full name that you're copying to.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['but']))
{
    $dir = 'uploads/';
    $fileCount = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo $fileCount;
    for($i=1;$i<=$fileCount;$i++)
    {
        $chemin = $dir.basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$chemin))
        {
            var_dump($_FILES);        
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error uploading ';
        }

    }
}

?>
```